# Why doesn't this (adapted) circuit work with the given power voltage?

Tags: zener, troubleshooting

I'm helping a little friend with his first project: an electronic dice [from Velleman](http://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?id=338494). The circuit is here (click to enlarge):
[image: The circuit]

He built it, I checked and improved it, everything was okay - *except we didn't had a 2V7 zener, so we used a 3V3 on for ZD1*.

We powered the device using a lab power supply at the given 9V, and it didn't work well: it showed sometimes a six (LEDs 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7), and sometimes a '7' (all LEDs). We had the luck that I thought the LEDs were too bright: I decreased the voltage to 6V, and then it worked...

This odd behaviour really comes from ZD1: later on, I replaced it with a 2V7 one and now everything's working fine on 9V (and 6V as well).

Can anyone explain why that is? Both ICs ([4046](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/HEF4046B.pdf) and [4024](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/HEF4024B.pdf)) are working properly on both 9V as 6V. I would expect that when you use a zener with a higher zener voltage, you'd need a higher voltage from the power supply rather than a lower.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope you're not using this "electronic die" for anything serious — it's loaded! The way the circuit is wired, it's twice as likely to show a 2 or a 3 as any other number.

In any case, the circuit comprising D1, D2, D3, R3, ZD1 and T1 is there to create a display with 6 LEDs lit whenever the counter value is "000". However, leakage current through T1 and ZD1 can allow the LEDs to light at other times. It's just a fact of life that low-voltage zeners have high leakage currents, and it only takes a few µA to turn on T1 in this application.

It's a dodgy circuit design however you look at it, and the better fix for the problem might be to increase the value of R3, to maybe 100K ohms. I would be inclined to eliminate ZD1 altogether, and instead put an ordinary silicon diode in series with T1's emitter lead. Or replace that whole mess with a proper 3-input NOR gate (CD4025).

Comment: Gheghe, I know. But good that you pointed it out!

Comment: Which way round would you put the diode? Are you sure it would achieve sufficient off voltage? Agree that proper NOR gate is much cleaner than trying to do it analogue.

Comment: @pjc50: It would point the same way as all the other diodes, with its anode connected to the power supply. It should be rather effective, since it carries the LED current as well as T1's base current. If T1 tries to conduct with its base held at Vcc-Vdiode (by one or more of D1-D3), the drop across this new diode will immediately cause a reduction in the Vbe that T1 sees.

Answer (score 1):

I've not done a full analysis, but I suspect the answer is that the base of T1 never gets low enough to turn off when the 3v3 zener is fitted. T1 is effectively a drive amplifier for the '6' case only, so turning on T1 lights all the LEDs but the center one.

D1-3, ZD1, and R3 make an interesting arrangement: T1 is biased off or almost-off unless Q1-3 are all low, at which point it turns on - but without sinking the base current through IC2.

Comment: Right, I see. It's an inverting circuit, so a _higher_ zener voltage needs a _lower_ power voltage. Decreasing the resistance of R3, would that make it work with 9V?

Comment: Decreasing R3 might make it work with a 3v3 zener, but it's a bit more subtle than that - the zener is not across the power rails, the relevant parameters are the transistor on/off currents and voltage. I suggest putting that bit of circuit into a simulator and experimenting, and looking at current and voltages at key points.